# Cannot change the value of a global variable

Tags: ios, swift, scope

I just wrote some Swift code for accessing Riot API, with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

I wrote a function `func getIDbyName(SummName: String) -> String` to get the summoner id.

As you can see from the code below, I am assigning the id to `self.SummID`.

After executing the function, I am able to `println` the correct id, for example `"1234567"`. However, the `return self.SummID` returns `"0"`, the same as assigned in the beginning.

I tried to mess with the code, but I simply cannot get the correct value of `self.SummID` outside of the `Alamofire.request` closure. It always remain `"0"` anywhere outside.

I think it has something to do with the scope of the variable. Does anyone know what is going on here?

```
import Foundation

import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class SummInfo {
    var SummName = "ThreeSmokingGuns"
    var SummID = "0"

    var SummChamp = "akali"
    var SummS1 = "flash"
    var SummS2 = "ignite"
    var SummRank = "Unranked"
    var SummWR = "-"        //summoner's winrate

    let api_key = "key"
    let URLinsert = "?api_key="

    init(SummName: String, SummChamp: String, SummS1: String, SummS2: String, SummRank: String, SummWR: String) {

        self.SummName = SummName
        self.SummChamp = SummChamp
        self.SummS1 = SummS1
        self.SummS2 = SummS2
        self.SummRank = SummRank
        self.SummWR = SummWR


    }

    init(SummName: String) {
        self.SummName = SummName
    }

    func getIDbyName(SummName: String) -> String
    {
        let SummURL = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"

        var fullURL = "\(SummURL)\(SummName)\(URLinsert)\(api_key)"

        Alamofire.request(.GET, fullURL)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                if let anError = error
                {
                    // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                    println("error calling GET on /posts/1")
                    println(error)
                }
                else if let data: AnyObject = data // hate this but responseJSON gives us AnyObject? while JSON() expects AnyObject
                    // JSON(data!) will crash if we get back empty data, so we keep the one ugly unwrapping line

                {
                    // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                    let post = JSON(data)
                    self.tempJ = post
                    var key = post.dictionaryValue.keys.array //not necessary
                    var key2 = post[SummName.lowercaseString].dictionaryValue.keys.array
                    self.SummID = post[key[0],key2[2]].stringValue  //[profileIconId, revisionDate, id, summonerLevel, name]


                    //test console output

                    println("The post is: \(post.description)")
                    println(SummName.lowercaseString)
                    println(key)
                    println(key2)
                    println(self.SummID)


                }


        }
      return self.SummID
    }
}
```

Comment: SummID is a property of the class SummInfo, so it does not need to be returned from getIDbyName. Also you don't need all those 'self.' References outside of the init - they are implicit in Swift. But otherwise it looks OK. Where are you checking the value of SummID and finding it still "0? The problem may be there.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am just putting println() at different points to check, as well as breakpoints. Returning SummID is really a desperate attempt to get the data I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, fullURL)
            .responseJSON
```

is an asynchronous call. This means that the call to getIDbyName will immediately return without waiting the responseJSON to finish. This is the exact reason why you get a the '0' value for ID that you have set initially.

Having said that, the solution is to have a call back closure in the **getIDbyName** method:

```
 func getIDbyName(SummName: String, callback: (id:String?) ->() ) -> ()
{
        let SummURL = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"

        var fullURL = "\(SummURL)\(SummName)\(URLinsert)\(api_key)"

        Alamofire.request(.GET, fullURL)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                if let anError = error
                {
                    // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                    println("error calling GET on /posts/1")
                    println(error)
                    //Call back closure with nil value  
                    callback(nil)  //Can additionally think of passing actual error also here


                }
                else if let data: AnyObject = data // hate this but responseJSON gives us AnyObject? while JSON() expects AnyObject
                    // JSON(data!) will crash if we get back empty data, so we keep the one ugly unwrapping line

                {
                    // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                    let post = JSON(data)
                    self.tempJ = post
                    var key = post.dictionaryValue.keys.array //not necessary
                    var key2 = post[SummName.lowercaseString].dictionaryValue.keys.array
                    self.SummID = post[key[0],key2[2]].stringValue  //[profileIconId, revisionDate, id, summonerLevel, name]


                    //test console output

                    println("The post is: \(post.description)")
                    println(SummName.lowercaseString)
                    println(key)
                    println(key2)
                    println(self.SummID)
                    //Pass the actual ID got.
                    callback(self.SummID)
                }


        }
      return self.SummID
    }
```

And clients should always use this API to fetch the latest ID, and can refer the attribute directly to get whatever is cached so far in SummID member.

Here is how to call this method-

```
object.getIDbyName(sumName){ (idString :String) in

      //Do whatever with the idString

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I read some of the other questions on asynchronous call, but I am kind of a noob at solving the problem. Do you have and solution for getting the data out.

Comment: I have edited my answer that solves the issue.  Please take look.